# Moving to previous directory given full path

Tags: javascript, node.js, file

Say we have a path, `C:/Users/me/projects`. I would like to, from that path, be able to navigate through the directories. For example I can do:

```
//Current directory, C:/Users/me/projects

const something = require('../file.js');
```

Which would point to the file `file.js` in the directory right behind. However, I would like to be able to go backwards just like that but given a full path, something like

```
console.log(__dirname + '/../')
```

Which would go backwards from the current directory. But of course, it doesn't work like that. It would just be `C:/Users/me/projects/../`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `path.resolve()`

`const path = require('path);
console.log(path.resolve(__dirname, '..'));`